# Chrome Extension Replace word in current textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that replaces the last word typed in the current `<textarea>` when the user makes a certain `keydown` event fire. So I've tried this but it doesn't really work.

Here are the files of my extension:

My extension's `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
 "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "replace test"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Its `background.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

And its `content_script.js`:

```
    document.onkeydown = replacePrevWord;  

// Azerty: Ctrl + ² 
// Qwerty: Ctrl + '
function KeyPress(e) {
    var evtobj = window.event? event : e
    if (evtobj.keyCode == 222 && evtobj.ctrlKey)
        return true;
}


function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;   // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
        ctrl.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
        Sel.moveStart('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
        return (CaretPos);
}


function returnWord(text, caretPos) {
    var index = text.indexOf(caretPos);
    var preText = text.substring(0, caretPos);
    if (preText.indexOf(" ") > 0) {
        var words = preText.split(" ");
        return words[words.length - 1]; //return last word
    }
    else {
        return preText;
    }
}


function replacePrevWord() {
    if(KeyPress()){
        var text = document.activeElement;
        var caretPos = getCaretPosition(text)
        var word = returnWord(text.value, caretPos);
        if (word != null) {
            text.value =  text.value.replace(word,"replaced");
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on JSFiddle (**http://jsfiddle.net/cyo646cr/3/**), but I don't know how to do this in a Chrome extension.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the `222` KeyCode? When i look at this list: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes `222` is a single quote. On whitch key do you want to do an action? `²`?

Comment: Oh i think i get it... `Ctrl + '` ?? That key does work for in the fiddle

Comment: I'm french on azerty keyboard and i forgot that ² doesn't exist in qwerty ^^
so yes it's Ctrl + ' for you ^^

Comment: Not sure but maybe you could do something with chrome.commands https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands

Comment: I've already try to adds commands on manifest but i never triggered them.. :/

Comment: Why do you support IE in your code when you develop a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) and the `scripting` permission and move `<all_urls>` to `host_permissions` instead of using the deprecated `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` with the `tabs` permission.

### Issue

You are not injecting the script correctly. It's easy to say, because calling this simple line

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

in your `background.js` will result in injecting the script only **one time** and in the current tab (because no tabId is specified). Therefore your script will run only once for every session of Google Chrome in the first tab you open.

Take a look at [**the documentation for `chrome.tabs.executeScript`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

### Work around

To work around this problem you've got two options:

1. Declare the `"content_scripts"` field in your `manifest.json` so it will be injected in any page that matches a pattern.
2. Add a listener with the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` method and inject the script on the tab.

### Option 1

Declare the `"content_scripts"` field in your `manifest.json` like this:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "all_frames": true
    }
],
...
```

Now your content script will be injected in every page (because `"<all_urls>"` will match all the pages) and in all the frames of the pages. You can find helpful informations about the `"content_scripts"` [**here**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

### Option 2

Request the permissions for the `chrome.tabs` API and the URLs you want in your `manifest.json`:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
]
...
```

In your `background.js`, add a listener to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`, which will fire on every tab update (i.e. url update), and inject your script using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabID, info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
```

See [**the documentation for `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

Comment: In option 1, you don't need to declare permissions explicitly for scripts declared in the manifest. Also, to be fully useful, explain why the current way of injecting is incorrect.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli thansk a lot