# Chrome Extension Pass Variable from popup.js to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have popup.js script:

```
function FireInjectionScript() {
    //Want to Pass this variable.
    var updateTextTo = document.getElementById('mat_no').value.trim()
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'InjectionScript.js'
    }); 
}

document.getElementById('caseButton').addEventListener('click', FireInjectionScript);
```

I have gone through pretty much every question in the the first 5 pages of google and stackoverflow and can't get this simple parameter pass working.

Have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645538/communicate-data-from-popup-to-content-script-injected-by-popup-with-executescri), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645538/communicate-data-from-popup-to-content-script-injected-by-popup-with-executescri), [this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging).  Many of the questions are rather old.  Is this not possible in chrome anymore ?  My ultimate goal is to pass the variable and then return data from a WebApi to fill out some controls on the page based on the variable passed - am I barking up the wrong tree.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to send the data to the injected script, but you need the tab Id.

**popup.js**

```
function FireInjectionScript() {
    //Want to Pass this variable.
    var updateTextTo = document.getElementById('mat_no').value.trim();
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{file: 'InjectionScript.js'},()=>{
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{myVar:updateTextTo});
        });
    }); 
}

document.getElementById('caseButton').addEventListener('click', FireInjectionScript);
```

**InjectionScript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message=>{
    if (message.myVar) {
        //here you can access message.myVar
    }
});
```

Comment: Nokonoko Gonna give it a go, I've tried this method but maybe the syntax was old

Comment: Works.  Must have had bad syntax from the code example I was using from old example