# In extension the callbacks are accumulating and persisting until browser restart

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am porting a chess game parser to new manifest v3 specification. When clicking context menu on a `selected text`, it plays visually the `selected text` as [PGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) chess game notation.
The problem is that background script on each game execution adds one more **chrome.runtime.onMessage** listener, and all the listeners persists until browser closed. So, all listeners are invoked and only first game is played each time.
There is the code:

```
//background.js
function playBoard (info, imgPath, windowAttributes)
{
   console.log("play board with: " + info.selectionText);
   let gameObject = {
                     chessObject:
                     {
                        gametype : "PGN_OR_FEN_board",
                        content : info.selectionText,
                        imgPath : imgPath
                     }
                  };
   let windowPromise = chrome.windows.create(windowAttributes);
   windowPromise.then((value) => {
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
         (request, sender, sendResponse) =>
         {
           console.log("backg: chrome.runtime.onMessage()> " + gameObject.chessObject.content);
           sendResponse(gameObject);
         }
       );
   });
}
```

The above code is invoked in following context:

```js
//background.js

console.log("enter global>");
var idParser     = "parser parent";
var idMiniBoard  = "board mini";
var idMediuBoard = "board medium";
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(

   (details)=>
   {
      console.log("on installing");
      idParser      = chrome.contextMenus.create({"id":idParser,     "title": "Chess Parser", "contexts":["selection"]});
      idMiniBoard   = chrome.contextMenus.create({"id":idMiniBoard,  "title": "Play Small",   "contexts":["selection"], "parentId": idRoatta});
      idMediuBoard  = chrome.contextMenus.create({"id":idMediuBoard, "title": "Play Medium",  "contexts":["selection"], "parentId": idRoatta});
      chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(menuItemClick);
      console.log("on installed");
   }
)
function menuItemClick(clickData, tab)
{
   switch (clickData.menuItemId)
   {
   case idMiniBoard:
      playBoard   (clickData, "mini18", {url: "board.html", type:"popup", height : 350, width : 350});
      return;
   case idMediuBoard:
      playBoard   (clickData, "medium35", {url: "board.html", type:"popup", height: 450, width: 450});
      return;
   }
}
```

There is the popup window startup code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
   (event) =>
   {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ chessObject: { gametype : "PGN_OR_FEN_board" } },
          (request) => //in fact is response, but is requested response
          {
             board_doc_main(request.chessObject);
          });

   }
);
```

I am trying to apply similar approach as I did for firefox, here [Firefox extension, identification of context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695395/firefox-extension-identification-of-context). Somehow for firefox this works. I am trying to implement like this: Popup open on click from background worker. Then popup window sends message to background worker to receive the required context, including the `selection game text`.
###################
UPDATE:
As suggested in response from @wOxxOm, this is exactly how I changed now

```js
function playBoard (clickData, imgPath, windowAttributes)
{
   let gameObject = {
                  chessObject:
                  {
                     gametype : "PGN_OR_FEN_board",
                     content : clickData.selectionText,
                     imgPath : imgPath
                  }
               };

   let windowPromise = chrome.windows.create(windowAttributes);
   windowPromise.then((wnd) => {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (
         function __playBoardCallback__ (request, sender, sendResponse)
         {
            if (sender.tab?.id === wnd.tabs[0].id)
            {
               chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(__playBoardCallback__);
               sendResponse(gameObject);
            }
         }
      );
   });

}
```

Comment: Either 1) use a named function for the onMessage listener and call removeListener inside or 2) simply [pass the info directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122).

Comment: No, the idea was to add a name after `function` and use it instead of `this`.

Comment: `this` in a function points to the global object, not to the function, so removeListener doesn't do anything. There is also no need to move anything if you do as I suggested...

Comment: To see the mistake you can add console.log(this) or inspect it in devtools. Just add a name to the function and don't move it, it'll use the variable in the outer scope just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unregister the listener immediately when it runs by using a named function:

```js
async function playBoard(info, imgPath, windowAttributes) {
  let gameObject = {
    // .........
  };
  const wnd = await chrome.windows.create(windowAttributes);
  const tabId = wnd.tabs[0].id;
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function _(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.tab?.id === tabId) {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(_);
      sendResponse(gameObject);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I left the promise as is and moved tabid logic inside ```then```, see update